# Manipulating an element using jquery not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

I have a regular div, like so:

```
<div id="registry_ViewPanel">
    <div id="registry_Header">Register</div>
    <div id="registry_Content">
       //Registry fields here
    </div>
</div>
```

with css:

```
#registry_ViewPanel {
    width:400px;
    height:400px;
    border:1px solid;
    background-color:#fff;
    display:none;
    position:fixed;
}
```

Here are some alerts I did using jquery:

```
alert($("#registry_ViewPanel").length);
alert($("#registry_ViewPanel").html());
alert($("#registry_ViewPanel").height());
alert($("#registry_ViewPanel").width());
```

Here are the results

```
1
//Displays everything inside of <div id="registry_ViewPanel"></div>
0
0
```

But when I look at `<div id="registry_ViewPanel"></div>` with firebug, there is nothing overriding the height or width...

Also, when I try to assign `.draggable();` or do `.fadeIn();` it doesn't work...

Any ideas of why this would happen? If you have any suspicions, even without enough information, please let me know and I will either provide more information or try out your idea.

Thanks,
Matt

Comment: Cut and pasted your code and it brings up 400 and 400 fine for height and width. Same with fadeIn. jQuery v1.3, yours?

Comment: jQuery v1.3.2. The weird thing is, it won't let me do anything to any elements with  registry or register in it... this makes absolutely no sense... but I changed all of them to be reg_ so now they work

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `height()` and `width()` functions gets the actual DOM object heights. Since a div with no content in it won't render at all, it yields 0. Use `css()` to get the CSS attributes, like karim79 mentions.

```
$("#thing").css("height");
```

Comment: There is content in it (I updated my question)... but you're right, doing .css('height') did return '400px'... why would doing .height() return 0?

Comment: I can't think of anything. The div in question is visible in the browser?

Comment: You have a display:none; for the div in question. This causes to get the dimensions as 0.

Comment: Not true. The registry_ViewPanel represents an in-browser popup to prompt the user for input. I have a similar one for login that uses the exact same css settings... display:none and .height() returns the proper height.

Comment: The div in question is not visible in the browser, but again the login_ViewPanel is also not visible in the browser and it works just fine

Answer (score 0):

A long shot... The only thing that comes to mind is that the entire document hasn't loaded/rendered yet, therefor the element doesn't have a width and height. Are you wrapping you jQuery code in a document ready()?

```
$(document).ready(function() {
   alert($("#registry_ViewPanel").length);
   alert($("#registry_ViewPanel").html());
   alert($("#registry_ViewPanel").height());
   alert($("#registry_ViewPanel").width());
});
```

Comment: it's already in $(document).ready(function() { }); thanks though